# Extract data from Principal in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, principal

I try extract data from Principal.

[principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uNYS.png)

How to do it? I need the login value from 'attributes' Collection.
principal doesn't have such methods.

Comment: please check my answer on another similar question - might help some... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66107609/57033

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can work. It's always a bit nasty to get those properties.

```
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public void user(Authentication authentication) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> properties = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) authentication.getDetails();
        String loginProperty = properties.get("login");
        //Do what you want to do with your property
    }
```

Comment: Why I can't use OAuth2Authentication in my @GetMapping("/authenticated") endpoint? I get exception: ```Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current user principal is not of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication]: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken@28f0d859: Principal: Name: [...], Granted Authorities: [[...]], User Attributes: [{...}]```

Comment: Hi Karol, i adjusted my answer. could you try with "Authentication" instead?

Comment: Your solution gives me 

(LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
```Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>'```

and 

return properties.get("login");
```Incompatible types.
Required:
org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
Found:
java.lang.Object```

Comment: That first is just a warning. The second is my bad. It shouldn't return anything, it was just an example on how to get the value out. Adjusting again.

Comment: And now I get: `Cannot resolve method 'getUserAuthentication()'`

Comment: Sorry, don't have my intellij open. Try without the .getUserAuthentication() (see updated answer).

Comment: It's just `java.lang.ClassCastException`, but `authentication.getDetails();` gives me some WebAuthenticationDetails and I need attributes from principal (DefaultOAuth2User)