# How to access java.security.Principal attributes inside Spring Boot controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, principal

I have an Angular frontend which prompts the user to login using Microsoft Azure Active Directory. The correct headers are added to the request when the user accesses my API.

My API is a Spring Boot Rest API secured according to this ([Protect a resource server/API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide#protect-a-resource-serverapi)) guide.

My controller has the following method using the java.security.Principal interface as a parameter.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
ResponseEntity<Object> test(Principal principal) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(principal);
}
```

When I set a breakpoint I see the attributes I want to get like ***principal.attributes.unique_name***, but I am not able to access those attributes through the Principal interface. Any idea on how to achieve this?

PS: I've had a look at similar questions like this one ([How to get all attributes from java.security.Principal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463803/how-to-get-all-attributes-from-java-security-principal)), but their answers were not able to help me...

Comment: Cast to `Authentication` and obtain it, or use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` on your method argument and use the user class you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this [Baeldung guide](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security#bean) you can get access to the principal via the SecurityContextHolder.

Casting this object to AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal provides access to the principle properties as follows.

```
AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = (AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
Map<String, Object> attributes = principal.getAttributes();
String name = String.valueOf(attributes.get("unique_name"));
```

Another option is to use the `AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal` directly in the controller parameters by using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation as pointed out in the comments below.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    ResponseEntity<String> test(@AuthenticationPrincipal AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = principal.getAttributes();
        String name = String.valueOf(attributes.get("unique_name"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(name);
    }
```

Comment: You can just cast the `Principal` to `AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal`. You don't need the static method calls for that.

Comment: You're right @M.Deinum, thanks for pointing that out. However when I try to use ```AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal``` directly as the type of my controller parameter I get ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attributes cannot be empty```. Any clue to why that's the case?

Comment: You cannot use that directly, unless you add the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation next to it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my answer accordingly.